# How to add missing Kentico libraries back in the CMS project

Tags: visual-studio, kentico

Visual Studio 2019 is showing a lot of libraries missing form the Kentico CMS project. I have tried cleaning/rebuilding, and targeting both .NET framework 4.6 and 4.7 without luck. This project was last published more than 6 months ago from Visual Studio 2017 and has been working fine.

When I opened it today and recompiled just to see, it failed. How do I add the missing libraries so it can compile again?

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: kentico libraries missing in visual studio screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each file you should be able to see the path of the file. Typically this will be in the Lib folder (at the same level as the CMS) folder. If they’re not in source control that might be the issues. If you know the version of Kentico, you can add the referenced back in with NuGet (search for Kentico.Libraries)

Comment: There are no files in the Lib folder with the extension .dll. All files are .dll.config, or .xml

Comment: I will try adding Kentico.Libraries nuget package.

Comment: Sounds like perhaps the .dll files were excluded in the .gitignore file perhaps?

Comment: DLLs might have been excluded in .tfignore or nuget.config. Tried adding Kentico.Libraries nuget package matching our version.hotfix (11.0.26). Yellow exclamation mark went away from some references but not all. I have the hotfix DLLs on my office PC, and will manually copy to my home PC. Lets see if that helps

Answer (score 2):

1. If lib folder doesn't have dlls. You can install fresh Kentico without DB to a separate folder and copy dll from there (just make sure it is the same version and hotfix as yours).
2. Without installing - just download your hotfix (you will find files in the lib folder there as well). You can copy from there.
3. You may try to switch to nugets. You need 2 mains ones: *Kentico.Libraries* and *Kentico.Libraries.Web.UI* (I have version working with nugets).

But honestly would be easier to go the 1st option.